# OpenCobolIDE and DB2 - Connection

Tags: db2, cobol

I'm currently working on a small COBOL project and I'm using OpenCobolIDE.
I also downloaded DB2 Express and I'm able to use it by running the "Commande line processor"

Now my question is the follow one : How can I make a connection between OpenCobolIDE and DB2 ?

I saw that it was possible to use "esqlOC" but I didn't find a lot of documentation and I'm still lost at the moment.

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that's it's against SO policy, but here is a link; http://db2twilight.blogspot.nl/2014/01/linuxdb2-running-cobol-with-inline-sql.html   The code isn't that long, but I found no disclaimer, so assumed copyright goes to the blogger, Dick Reitveld.  The post is a tutorial on linking DB2 to GnuCOBOL (was OpenCOBOL), and not how to inform the OpenCOBOLIDE how to do the build, but hopefully this fits in with your question.

The build rules are listed in a shell script on the same page.

Basically it comes down to, creating a COBOL source file with EXEC SQL statements, running them  through the DB2 preprocessor, then compiling the generated sources with cobc.

```
db2 connect to sample 
db2 prep program.sqb bindfile target ANSI_COBOL
cobc program.cbl -static -Wall -L/path/to/db2libs/sqllib/lib64 -ldb2 -v -x -save-temps -O
db2 bind program.bnd
db2 connect reset
```

Where "program" is your filename, with .sqb inputs and will generate .cbl and .bnd, and the

```
-L/path/to/.../
```

is the full path to where your DB2 install has placed the DB2 support libraries.